# Anyway of doing a foreach with only one data set without errors or repeating code?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Just looking for some advise, I have written some simple PHP Scritps that load in an XML file, process data and pass through to an API. 
Everything is working, But the code is ugly.

for example:

```
if ( count( $XMLfile->Node )<2 ) {
// Here i will have all my code to run if the Root Node is only 1
} else {
  foreach( $XMLfile->Node as $Node) {   
// Here i will run the exact same code again if i have more than one Node
}
```

The cleanest way i know, is to have the code in a function, and then include the function in the if and foreach, this way i am not repeating the same code and it makes managing it much easier.

But is this the best method?

Comment: is the structure not the same irrespective of how many nodes you have? is the condition necessary at all?

Comment: Foreach errors if the node is only one, It still works correct, but i dont like code erroring and cluttering my error_logs, when i am looking for other errors.